# create dynamic geometry point from WKTElement geoalchemy2

Tags: postgis, geoalchemy-2

I have a function

```
def get_centres(origin_lat, origin_long):
     pt = WKTElement('POINT({0} {1})'.format(origin_long, origin_lat), srid=4326)
     centres = Centres.query.with_entities(Centres,functions.ST_Distance_Sphere(Centres.location,pt).label('distance')).all()
```

The query it creates when I run the above function is

```
 `[SQL: 'SELECT kare.centres.id AS kare_centres_id, kare.centres.name AS kare_centres_name, kare.centres.address1 AS kare_centres_address1, kare.centres.address2 AS kare_centres_address2, kare.centres.city AS kare_centres_city, kare.centres.postcode AS kare_centres_postcode, ST_AsEWKB(kare.centres.location) AS kare_centres_location, ST_Distance_Sphere(kare.centres.location, ST_GeomFromText(%(ST_GeomFromText_1)s, %(ST_GeomFromText_2)s)) AS distance \nFROM kare.centres'] [parameters: {'ST_GeomFromText_1': 'POINT((-1.3686658,) (50.9965899,))', 'ST_GeomFromText_2': 4326}]`
```

This query throws an error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.InternalError) parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "POINT((-" <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry
```

The problem is WKTElement is converting geometry point to

```
'POINT((-1.3686658,) (50.9965899,))'
```

When postgress sql is expecting below format.

```
`POINT(-1.3686658 50.9965899)`
```

I copy the query from above and run it on a Postgres Sql client and it throws the same "invalid geometry" error.

When I format the point and run the query I get the results.

How do I pass the right geometry point

Comment: Can you tell what is going into the function: `get_centres(origin_lat, origin_long):` ?

Comment: a lat long valu example get_centres(50.9965899,-1.3686658)

Comment: It seems that parenthesis are added to 'origin_lat' before it goes into the function. Did you check that? And what happens if you do it without the `.format(origin_long, origin_lat)` ?

Comment: you are correct. I tried just `WKTElement('POINT(-1.3686658 50.9965899)', srid=4326)` and it seemed to create the point without parenthesis. So that begs the question, how do I create a point on runtime then ?

Comment: I see the problem your first suggestion was correct. The function get_centres is getting tuples as values and not the actual values.